# Show modal window without button press in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I am doing a project and I want to show a modal window to compulsorily accept some Cookies.
I need that cookie window to be launched automatically, without pressing any button, when the application starts, that is, before the dashboard is loaded.

This is my code:

ModalCookie.js

```
imports ...

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
};

export default function CookiesModal() {
  
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

   const handleClose = () => {
     setCookiesPreview(false);
     setOpen(false);
   };

  const handleNotClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason == "backdropClick") 
        return;
}

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('1');
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };


  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div>

      <Fade in={open}>
        <Box>
        <BootstrapDialog
                onClose={handleNotClose}
                
                aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
                open={open}
                closeAfterTransition 
                BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                BackdropProps={{
                timeout: 500,
                }}
              >
                <BootstrapDialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
                  
                </BootstrapDialogTitle>

          
              <TabContext value={value}>
                <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
                  <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
                    <Tab 
                      label="AAAAA" 
                      value="1" />           
                  </TabList>
                </Box>
                <TabPanel value="1">
                  <p>...</p>
                </TabPanel>

              </TabContext>

              <Button 
                  onClick={handleClose}
                  variant="contained" 
                  color="secondary"
                  
              >
                Aceptar
              </Button>
              </BootstrapDialog>
            </Box>
          </Fade>              
        
      
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Config.js

```
// COOKIES
export const setCookiesPreview = ( state ) => {
  localStorage.setItem('cookiesPreview', state)
}
// --
export const isCookiesPreview = () => {
  const active=localStorage.getItem('cookiesPreview') ? localStorage.getItem('cookiesPreview') : true;
  setCookiesPreview(false);

  return( 
    active  
  );
}
```

And my dashboard:

```
imports...

// MAIN
export const Dashboard = () => {
  const state = useSelector( state => state);

  console.log('isCookiesPreview='+isCookiesPreview());

  if(isCookiesPreview()){
    console.log('CookiesPreview ON ------------------------------------------------')
    
    setTimeout(() => { 
      CookiesModal.handleOpen();
    }, 15000);  
  } 

  return (
    <>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <div>
              <HeaderBar/>
              
              {(alertMessage != null) && (alertMessage.length>0) ? <Alert severity={alertSeverity}>{alertMessage}</Alert> : <></>}

              <Grid container item={true} xs={12}>
                  <BodyGrid/>
              </Grid>

              <Grid container item={true} xs={12} pt={4}>
                  <BottomBar/>                    
              </Grid>

          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  )
```

I am trying to use the handleOpen() constant from ModalCookie.js to open the window from Dashboard.js and save the locale that those cookies have been accepted so as not to show it the following times

I can't get the window to show up, but it does show me the logs I've put on the Dashboard related to cookies.

It tells me that HandleOpen is not a function.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [mre], specifically the part about making your example **minimal**.

Comment: Have you tried to set the initial state to true ?  `const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);`

Comment: Also, add a `<CookiesModal/>` tag to your dashboard, under your `<ThemeProvider>`

Comment: UncaughtTypeError:
CookieModal.default.handleOpem is not a function.

The error persists even with those changes and ends up giving a timeOut